# CMD - Java package not found

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd

I'm trying to write a client-server application in Java through Eclipse. This is the code:

```
package edu.fcps.ab;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestServer {
    public static Vector<String> messages = new Vector<String>();
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter port number");
        int port = scan.nextInt();
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket s = serverSock.accept();
            int messageLength = 0;
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while(true) {
                if(messages.size() > messageLength) {
                    for(int i = messageLength; i < messages.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.println(messages.get(i));
                    }
                    messageLength = messages.size();
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred");
        }

    }
}

package edu.fcps.ab;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class TestClient implements Runnable{
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        TestClient tc = new TestClient();
        Thread t = new Thread(tc);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter port");
        int port = s.nextInt();
        String ip = "127.0.0.1";
        try {
            Socket sock = new Socket(ip, port);
            System.out.println("Successfully connected");
            System.out.println("Enter username");
            String username = s.next();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String sent;
            while(true) {
                sent = stdin.readLine();
                if(sent != null) {
                    TestServer.messages.add(username + ": " + sent);
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The code compiles fine in Eclipse, but when I try to compile the client through the command-line I get this error:

```
TestClient.java:31: error: package TestServer does not exist
                                        TestServer.messages.add(username + ": " + sent);
```

The server and client files are in the same package. Why is this error happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: How do you compile on the command line? Please post the exact command that you use.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt within the edu.fcps.ab directory: javac TestServer.java or javac TestClient.java

Comment: If you compile Client separately, then you should include Server class in your classpath at compile time.

Comment: @EhsanKhodarahmi how would you do that?

Comment: Don't compile them separately, compile as `javac TestServer.java TestClient.java`.

Comment: @xXGETREKTXx you can do it through `-cp` flag of `javac`